# Does the change of "y" to "ies" in plural form of words have a phonological explanation?

Tags: phonology, linguistics

I've been looking for phonological rules or explanation for the change that occurs in -ies ending plural form but all I found was : When we have a vowel before "y" we add "s", such as "boys".
When we have a consonant before "y" it becomes "ies", such as "bunnies"

Comment: Interesting question.  A good starting point for you might be to have a look at this discussion on Stack Exchange. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34029/origin-of-pluralisation-of-verbs-and-nouns-in-english

Comment: monkey and pulley add s. but puppy, puppies. Interestingly, money can be monies or moneys. So.....